# Grails Command Object Limitation?

Tags: grails

I have an incoming POST method that has a form element 'message' that is a string that exceeds 64k in length.

If I use a command object to capture the parameters, this form element fails to capture the whole string.

If I get the form element from the params['element'], then I get the whole string. Is this a limit on the Grails Command Object implementation?

```
def update(CrcProtectedMessage msg) {
    def mess = params['message']
    msg.message = mess

    try {
        AuthorityUpdater command = new AuthorityUpdater(msg)
    ...
    do other stuff
    ...
}
```

seems to work. But without getting the 'message' from the params and setting it on the command object fails.

Grails 2.4.2

Java 8

Comment: Something odd is going on then with your actual code because I haven't hit this limitation with any version of Grails thus far up to 2.4.2 and I have command object classes (hundreds) with plenty long data. I suggest you edit your question to contain more specific code that is actually having the problem and not just some pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I edited the code. If I remove the two lines after the method signature, then the msg.message is null going into the AuthorityUpdater constructor. If I leave those two lines in place it works fine. This only happens when the 'message' value in the POST body exceeds 64k. Interestingly, If I try to create a String variable with the string value in the POST body in the Groovy Console 

    def msg = '''
    <POST BODY variable>
    '''

I get a compile error saying that the string is too long.

Comment: Does the command have any constraints?